# Accelstepper motor button stop and continue to next position

Tags: arduino

What I like to do is make a stepper motor run into one direction till a sensor gives a HIGH signal, then it should stops.

I figured this part out, but now I want the stepper proceed turning after a delay of a few seconds with the sensor signal still HIGH

Can somebody help me?

```cpp
#include <AccelStepper.h>
#define HALFSTEP 8

// Motor pin definitions
#define motorPin1  3     // IN1 on the ULN2003 driver 1
#define motorPin2  4     // IN2 on the ULN2003 driver 1
#define motorPin3  5     // IN3 on the ULN2003 driver 1
#define motorPin4  6     // IN4 on the ULN2003 driver 1

// Initialize with pin sequence IN1-IN3-IN2-IN4 for using the AccelStepper with 28BYJ-48
AccelStepper stepper1(HALFSTEP, motorPin1, motorPin3, motorPin2, motorPin4);



void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(7,INPUT);

  stepper1.setMaxSpeed(600);
  stepper1.setAcceleration(200);
  stepper1.setSpeed(100); 
}

void loop(){  

    if(digitalRead(7) == 1)  
    {
        stepper1.move(640000);
        stepper1.run();
    }

    if(digitalRead(7) == 0)   
    {
        stepper1.setCurrentPosition(0); 
        stepper1.stop();

        //from here it does not work, the stepper is not going to move
        delay(2000);

        stepper1.move(640000);
        stepper1.run();     
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) This clearly is not C! Arduino is not C! 2) This is no consulting service! See [ask].

Comment: Hmm, ok, sorry, it was an overly enthusiastic editor. But 2) stands.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine: Don't add unrelated tags to questions!

Comment: Sorry about that. I just wanted syntax highlighting but maybe it can be added without tagging.

Comment: It is just my home project, but I cant find the right solution. I figured people liked to help with these kind of problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think at your program as a loop that runs a 1000 times a sec.
so every time it reaches this section

```
if(digitalRead(7) == 0)   
    {
        stepper1.setCurrentPosition(0); 
        stepper1.stop();

        //from here it does not work, the stepper is not going to move
        delay(2000);

        stepper1.move(640000);
        stepper1.run();     
    }
```

it will stop for 2 sec. then move the stepper one step and then it starts over again. This is because .run() function only move the stepper one step each time it's called.

I would do something like this:

At the top define a new variable to check if the input was low at last loop.

`bool inputWasLow = true;`

Then in your loop try this

```
if(digitalRead(7) == 1)  
{
    inputWasLow = true;
    stepper1.runSpeed();
}

if(digitalRead(7) == 0)   
{
    if(inputWasLow) 
    {
        inputWasLow = false;
        stepper1.stop();
        delay(2000);
    }
    stepper1.runSpeed();   
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Perfect! that worked perfectly, Thank you very much! :D

Comment: Glad i could help. It would be great if you would mark my post as answered!